# How to change PyQtGraph context menu font size?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to change the font size of the menu whenever you right click on the plot in PyQtGraph. When I change the font size of the entire application using `setStyleSheet`, it also changes the font size of the menu.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

I don't want to individually change the font-size of the button because I have many other widgets in the GUI so I changed the `app` font-size. But it also changes the font-size of the plot menu. How can I make the font-size of the menu smaller? Either changing the font-size smaller or somehow making the menu larger so the words don't cut off would work.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    main_window = QtGui.QMainWindow()

    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(main_layout)
    main_window.setCentralWidget(widget)

    button = QtGui.QPushButton('hello')

    plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
    plot = plot_widget.plot()

    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(button)
    layout.addWidget(plot_widget)

    main_layout.addLayout(layout)
    main_window.show()

    app.setStyleSheet('QWidget {font-size: 30px}')

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the MWE that you have provided <sup>(1)</sup> the solution is to create another rule in QSS to set the font of QMenu and its children widgets:

```py
app.setStyleSheet("""
    QWidget {font-size: 30px}
    QMenu {font-size: 15px}
    QMenu QWidget {font-size: 15px}
""")
```

---

<sub>(1) For a more complex widget my solution could modify other parts, so there is no general solution but it depends on the widget itself.</sub>